# Text and emoji extraction from HTML

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

I need to perform text and emoji extraction from HTML (I have no control over the HTML I get). I found it fairly simple to remove HTML tags using the following function; however, it strips out the emojis embedded within an `<img>` tag. The result should be plain text + emoji characters.

I don't care much about spaces, but the cleaner it is, the better.

```
// this cleans the HTML quite well, but I need to extend it to keep the emojis
const stripTags = (html: string, ...args) => {
    return html.replace(/<(\/?)(\w+)[^>]*\/?>/g, (_, endMark, tag) => {
        return args.includes(tag) ? "<" + endMark + tag + ">" : ""
    }).replace(/<!--.*?-->/g, "")
}
```

```
<div>
   <div class="text-bold">
      <span dir="auto">
         <div>
            <div dir="auto" style="text-align: start;">Herman is 10 and was born in Louisiana. he now lives a wonderful life in Wisconsin.</div>
         </div>
         <div class="">
            <div dir="auto" style="text-align: start;">he's (mostly) a Beagle and Jack Russell mix.</div>
         </div>
         <div class="">
            <div dir="auto" style="text-align: start;">
               <span class=""><img height="16" width="16" alt="" src="https://someweb.com/images/emoji/bpp/2/16/1f415.png"></span> : @House… 
               <div class="" role="button" tabindex="0">Something else</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Expected output:

```
Herman is 10 and was born in Louisiana. he now lives a wonderful life in Wisconsin.
he's (mostly) a Beagle and Jack Russell mix. : @House… Something else.
```

Comment: Offtopic: `DIV`  (block-level) inside a `SPAN` (inline-contextual) is invalid HTML markup.

Comment: Also, Never, ever use RegExp to parse HTML. Use a proper DOMParser.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it doesn't really matter in my case + I don't have control over the input.

Comment: Never is a strong word:) If you have a solution that's fairly straightforward and efficient, feel free to share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use dom parser instead of pure regexp and get more control over HTML, here's an example how to achieve this one:

```
const htmlString = "<div>your contet...</div>";

const toRawString = (htmlString) => {
  if (!htmlString) {
    return null;
  }

  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const parsedHTML = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

  // Get all images and keep only alt attribute content
  // So if you need some data from other attributes you can reuse this one below
  const images = parsedHTML.querySelectorAll("img");
  images.forEach((image) => {
    const altSpan = document.createElement('span');
    altSpan.innerHTML = image.alt;
    image.parentElement.appendChild(altSpan);
    image.parentElement.removeChild(image);
  });

  // Replace all additional spaces
  return parsedHTML.body.textContent.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Best to use a DOM parser and traverse the DOM to extract the plain text.

Here is a solution using regex if you accept that this might fail in some corner cases.

```js
let html = `<div>
   <div class="text-bold">
      <span dir="auto">
         <div>
            <div dir="auto" style="text-align: start;">Herman is 10 and was born in Louisiana. he now lives a wonderful life in Wisconsin.</div>
         </div>
         <div class="">
            <div dir="auto" style="text-align: start;">he's (mostly) a Beagle and Jack Russell mix.</div>
         </div>
         <div class="">
            <div dir="auto" style="text-align: start;">
               <span class=""><img height="16" width="16" alt="" src="https://someweb.com/images/emoji/bpp/2/16/1f415.png"></span> : @House… 
               <div class="" role="button" tabindex="0">Something else</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>`;

let plain = html
  .replace(/<img .*?alt="([^"]+)"[^>]*>/g, ' $1 ') // extract alt text from img tag
  .replace(/<\/?[a-z][^>]*>/g, ' ') // remove all tags
  .replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim(); // cleanup whitespace
console.log(plain);
```

Output:

`Herman is 10 and was born in Louisiana. he now lives a wonderful life in Wisconsin. he's (mostly) a Beagle and Jack Russell mix.  : @House… Something else`

Please note that this not foolproof. For example it does not support corner cases, such as `<span title="Home > Edit">`, which should be written as  `<span title="Home &gt; Edit">`, but not always is.

**EDIT**

If you use jQuery it is easy to traverse an element in memory:

```
let html = `<div>...</div>`; // (same as above)
let elem = $(html); // create jQuery element in memory
elem.find('img').replaceWith(function() {
  return ' ' + $(this).attr('alt') + ' ';
});
let plain = elem.text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
```

Result:

`Herman is 10 and was born in Louisiana. he now lives a wonderful life in Wisconsin. he's (mostly) a Beagle and Jack Russell mix.  : @House… Something else`